# Find intervals with an increase of at least x% in a sliding window of y%

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

[You can download the dataframe csv from here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RFhe7_zAyB2OTCNILaRQElJ_jfpfDMya/view?usp=share_link)

I would like to find intervals of type `[a,b]` from inside a sliding window of size `n`, where `a` represents the minimum value, and `b` the maximum value inside the sliding window, so that the percentage change between a and b denoted by `a/b - 1` is greater than `y`.

I am using a timeseries dataframe looking like this

```
                  ts      pair  volume  price               ts-dt
0      1641008041000  FARMUSDT   0.000  161.8 2022-01-01 03:34:01
1      1641008042000  FARMUSDT  30.921  161.8 2022-01-01 03:34:02
2      1641008043000  FARMUSDT   5.088  161.8 2022-01-01 03:34:03
3      1641008044000  FARMUSDT   0.694  161.6 2022-01-01 03:34:04
4      1641008045000  FARMUSDT   9.352  161.9 2022-01-01 03:34:05
...              ...       ...     ...    ...                 ...
40078  1641048119000  FARMUSDT   1.518  200.2 2022-01-01 14:41:59
40079  1641048120000  FARMUSDT   8.988  200.1 2022-01-01 14:42:00
40080  1641048121000  FARMUSDT  36.576  200.1 2022-01-01 14:42:01
40081  1641048122000  FARMUSDT   5.133  200.0 2022-01-01 14:42:02
40082  1641048123000  FARMUSDT   0.279  199.8 2022-01-01 14:42:03
```

So far I have tried finding local minimas and maximas using: `argrelextrema` and `find_peaks` from scipy package, and most of the time I think I got somehow good results by playing with the distance parameter of find peaks function. However, this isn't exactly correct as the distance is the difference between two identical peaks (either max or min) and I want the distance between min and max to be at most `n`.

I feel like I'm on the wrong track and that there should be an easier solution out there.
I have also tried something like this with similar results to argrelextrema.

```
seconds[['min', 'max']] = seconds['price'].rolling(3600, center=True).agg(['min', 'max'])
seconds['min'] = seconds[seconds['price'] == seconds['min']]['price']
seconds['max'] = seconds[seconds['price'] == seconds['max']]['price']
```

Intervals should be looking something like this
[image: Intervals should be looking something like this]